# How do I use classes from another project in the same solution in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, linker, reference, project, projects-and-solutions

I'm working on a object-oriented Windows API wrapper library, written in C++, and I have two projects inside the solution:

- The actual library project;
- A "test" project, where I write code that uses the library for testing purposes.

My goal is to be able to include and use the library header files on the test project, as if it was an actual project that uses the library.

I solved the file inclusion problem by adding "$(SolutionDir)" to the test project's additional include directories (is there a cleaner way?), but I'm struggling to get the test project to link. I get unreferenced externals errors, which I assume is because the linker can't find the DLL.

I'm completely lost here. I have set up project-to-project references, so that the test project is dependent on the library project, but that did not solve the linking problem. I couldn't find any option in either project's properties that seemed to be relevant to my problem.

Is there a way I can simply hit "Build Solution" and then run the executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project's properties > Linker > Input, there's a bunch of settings you can specify for the linker, such as, for instance, additionnal dependencies to link with (put the .lib generated by your other project there) and which paths to look for said libraries.

Comment: Your solution worked great, but for that I had to set the library project's configuration type to static library, so it doesn't generate a DLL. Is there any way I can make this work with dynamic libraries?

Comment: When you build a dynamic library, it generates two files: a .lib and a .dll. The .lib contains linking information for the .dll, and has to be statically linked to your project. The .dll will then be loaded at runtime, so you just make sure your program finds it. Just put in the same directory as your application.